# Check if a string ends with a specific character and remove it - error "invalid identifier"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script which should check if the cell values in a range end with ",". If so, the comma is removed.

```
Dim Bereich As Range
Dim Zeilen As Long
Dim Zelle As Range
Dim str As String

Zeilen = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Bereich = Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(Zeilen, 19))

For Each Zelle In Bereich

str = Zelle.Value

If str.EndsWith(",") Then
str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)
Zelle.Value = str
End If

Next Zelle
```

However, in the line

```
 If str.EndsWith(",") Then
```

I get the errror-message "invalid identifier". But I can't find the fault in my script.
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The string data type does not have properties or methods in VBA.  VBA is not the same as VB.

Comment: If `Right$(str, 1) = "," Then`.

Comment: @BigBen whats the difference between `Right` and `Right$`?

Comment: @MG92 - the first returns a `Variant/String` while the second returns a `String`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, VBA is different from VB; the string data type does not have properties or methods in VBA.

In this case, change

```
If str.EndsWith(",") Then
```

to

```
If Right$(str, 1) = "," Then
```

Side note: considering using a different variable than `str` as this shadows the [`Str`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) function.